# Jira Search - Ticket Id starts with "" & Other filters

Tags: jira

How to Search Jira Tickets starts with "KN-" and Labels = 'Some Text' and Status = OPEN

How to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project in (KN) and labels = "Some text" and status = Open

Jira issue keys start with the project key

Comment: unfortunately, subqueries don't work and i want to query tickets with an epic in a project.  I was hoping to use something `parent like KN-*`.

Answer (score 0):

Working below query:

```
project in (KN) AND component = "Data Work" and status = Open ORDER BY updated DESC
```

Comment: unfortunately, subqueries don't work and i want to query tickets with an epic in a project. I was hoping to use something parent like KN-*.